# Не распространяется сессия на всю программу

Tags: c#, авторизация, сессия, wcf, аутентификация

У меня клиент - серверное приложение. Для идентификации пользователя использую сессии. Алгоритм таков:

- клиент отправляет на сервер логин и пароль
- сервер проверяет, если комбинация верна - создаёт сессию и заносит сессию и логин, к которому подходит сессия, в БД

Только проблема в том, что сессия распространяется только на ту форму, с которой шла отправка данных на сервер, а после того как я залогинился и перешёл на форму2, на неё уже не работает сессия.

Можно ли как-то присвоить второй форме сессию? Или я просто рано её создаю?

Comment: Добавте метку языка програмирования.

Comment: если это php, то возможно на второй форме вы просто не запускаете session_start().

Comment: Нет , C# с использованием WCF Сервиса

Answer (score 0):

Вы на второй форме создаете новый экземпляр сервиса? Если да, то понятно, почему нет сессии - в новом экземпляре ее нет. Можете сделать один экземпляр сервиса, который нужно будет передавать во все формы. Либо хранить сессию в MemoryCache и при каждом запросе вставлять ее в заголовки.

Comment: То есть мне нужно создать какой то класс на стороне клиента в котором я создаю экземпляр сервиса,и передаю в качестве параметра  id сессии,и после обработки сервером данных записать в этот экземпляр класса сессию ?
И на новых формах получается создавать экземпляр этого класса ?
Как то так ?

Comment: Если вы приложите свой клиентский код, смогу помочь с кодом.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_okr5KpmZBRS3BPMXBBTjVnUnM
Вот архив клиент + сервер.Только там еще БД есть в связке,если нужно будет - тоже отправлю.

Comment: [Исправления](https://gist.github.com/Markeli/b9baceab357b08a0447b1907eda1154e)

Comment: Работоспособность не проверил, без базы проблематично. Это самое простое решение.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Z22BX03Id6dDlaeXBJTjgzVHc/view
Вот база данных еще,напиши пожалуйста если у вас получиться / не получиться,я тогда другой метод искать буду

Comment: Что то не получается создать клиента которого я буду передавать во все остальные формы,можете подсказать как примерно это должно выглядеть ?
Вроде передаю старого клиента во вторую форму,но на неё сессия всё равно не распространяется

Comment: Странно. Попробуйте переделать так, как [советует Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff405740.aspx)

Comment: Изучите тему dependency injection, на пример AutoFac. Создайте сервис, который будет устанавливать соединение, и предоставлять доступ к этому соединению. Зарегистрируйте сервис в контейнере и ижектируйте его в каждую форму где хотите работать с этим соединением.

Comment: Ну а если у вас все равно нет промежуточного слоя бизнес логики, то можете сделать статический синглтон, и юзать через него соединение.